# Insert a specific Python global package to Conda environment

Tags: python, pythonpath, anaconda3

In a conda environment, I'm using a Python package that doesn't work properly when I install it locally with conda or pip. However, it works perfectly when I install it with apt package manager. Of course, I cannot import the package in conda environment because it searches in local Python paths.
I tried the following command:

```
export PYTHONPATH=/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages:$PYTHONPATH
```

which it works but I don't want to insert all the global Python packages. Then I tried:

```
export PYTHONPATH=/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/<specific_package_folder>:$PYTHONPATH
```

but unfortunately it doesn't work.

Any suggestions ?

Answer (score 1):

Finally I resolved the above issue using the following command:

```
ln -s /usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/<specific_package_folder>* /path/to/anaconda3/envs/envName/lib/python3.6/site-packages
```

With this way, I managed to link a global Python package with my local Conda environment.